# How to plot hundreds of gps coords with 100km radii around each one in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I have a few hundred GPS coords stored in a mysql DB. They are of major cities across the globe. I need to put these points on a map, with a 100km semi-transparent radius circle around each point.

How does one go about doing that?

Comment: google maps api v3 can plot circles - that's what you probably want

Answer (score 0):

Try [KML](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html).  It uses tags, in a fashion similar to XML, to create objects that can be imported into Google Earth.  You may want to create `<Geometry>` objects consisting of a `<Point>` and a `<LineString>` for each of your locations.  Since [it is not possible to draw a circle directly, you will have to define many points that are equidistant from the city to create something that looks like a circle](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/faq.html#circle).

Use whatever glue language you prefer for parsing the coordinate data from your DB and generating a KML file.  It should be fairly straightforward once you've figured out how to do it with one data point.

Comment: Isnt there some sort of API function that draws a radius around a point straight in Google Maps? Calculating these points and plotting them manually for radii is not gonna be fun.

Comment: As Tomas mentioned, the Javascript API for Google Maps allows you to draw circles.  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools